# How to update a separate components props after performing a mutation with Apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, graphql, apollostack

With redux, when the state changes it updates any components props that is `connect`ed to the store with `mapStateToProps`. However with Apollo when performing a mutation, any component that is using the same data receive the new props.

I understand this is expected behaviour because Apollo doesn't know that the data sets are the same. Here's an example of what I'm getting at:

```
const query = gql`query { me { username } }`

@graphql(query)
class Header extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <h1>{this.props.data.me.username}</h1>
  }
}

const mutation = gql`mutation updateAccount($username: String!) {
  updateAccount(username: $username) {
    me {
      username
    }
  }
}`
@graphql(mutation)
class Edit extends React.Component {
  render () {
    # ...
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.mutate({variables: {username: this.state.username})
  }
}
```

The `Header` component renders out the `username`, where as the Edit component updates the `username`. I want to re-render `Header` when `username` changes. I'm not sure how to do this without polling the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apollo keeps an internal cache of queries and is able to normalize the result sets with [dataIdFromObject](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#dataIdFromObject) using the internal cache kept in the redux store.

In order to use the internal cache you must set `dataIdFromObject` when initializing your client:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  dataIdFromObject: o => o.id
})
```

Then when performing a mutation, ensure the `id` is returned in the return type:

```
const mutation = gql`mutation updateAccount($username: String!) {
  updateAccount(username: $username) {
    me {
      id
      username
    }
  }
}`
```

The query should also contain the id:

```
const query = gql`query { me { id username } }`
```

Apollo will recognise that the `id` is identical between the query and the return type of the mutation and update the query data accordingly.

I'm using Global ID's in my GraphQL API so the `id` is always unique across types but if you are using auto-increment ids or they are not unique then you can use `__typename` from the object:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  dataIdFromObject: o => `${o.__typename}:${o.id},`
})
```